# Length constraint of HTML content to be generated as PDF using mpdf in php

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using mpdf library to generate pdf from html(table) content in php. I am using below code

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $html=$_POST['html'];
    include 'mpdf.php';
    $mpdf=new mPDF(); 
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output();
    exit;
    ?>
```

When the size of html table is small, say about 100 rows, then PDF is generated properly. But when size of table is more, say about 1000-2000 rows, then pdf is not generated. Is there any size constraint in mpdf? What can be done to solve this problem? Or is there any other better library to generate pdf's in php

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely caused by PHP reaching maximum allowed memory and being killed. To confirm this, enable error reporting and run the script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

If you will get a message about exceeded memory limit, then you can try to increase in in your .php script (add at the begining after `<?php`):

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

If this still gives same error, increase it to `512M` or something like that. If you want to change `memory_limit` permanenty, then you can edit `php.ini` and set it there.

Comment: Where can I get error message? I am not getting any errors on running  script

Comment: Anyway I have tried increasing memory limit to 256,512 and 1024 .. still pdf not generated